# Нужно сделать логирование действий пользователей в проложении с записью в ДБ

Tags: android, log4j, context

Количество элементов в приложении очень велико, и писать в каждом слушателе метод для записи события - это слишком долго и черевато "пропуском" функциональностей.

Я подумал, можно для каждой класса **`Activity`**, хранить `static Context ctx`, -  **`ctx`** передавать, как переменную в класс  для извлечения из него событий:

1. Срабатывания слушателей.
2. Смена статуса жизненного цикла активности.

Вопрос: Как мне "ловить" срабатывания `Listener`-ов и `onStart()`,`onRestart()`,`onResume()`,`onPause()`,`onStop()`,`onDestroy()` из контекста другого класса?

P/S Возможно, необходимо передавать не контекст, а что-то иное. Возможно необходимо переопределить методы родительских классов и т.д.. Может есть уже готовые решения, библиотеки, фреймворки...

Answer (score 1):

Существует более простой, а главное правильный вариант.
Ужно реализовать интерфейс `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, а потом в собственно реализации класса `Application` вызвать метод `android.app.Application#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` и все.

В методах реализации интерфейса `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` вы получите вызовы всех методов жизненного цикла каждой активити вашего приложения.
Главное никогда не используйте активити, приходящие в этих методах на прямую! Никогда!

Думаю на просторох интернета можно найти примеры использования `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то для отлова onStart(),onRestart(),onResume(),onPause(),onStop(),onDestroy() нужно создать базовую activity и в ней в этих методах определить запись в бд. А остальные активити пусть от нее наследуются. С listener чуть посложнее но можно также создать в базовой активити какой нибудь метод записи действия в бд. и на каждом вызове listenerа вызывать его с меткой какой-нибудь